# Remove the default 00:00:00 time in daily bar plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to plot daily bar data:

```
pd.DataFrame( data=np.arange(10), index=pd.date_range( '2014/1/1', periods=10, freq='D' ) ).plot( kind='bar' )
```

But the labels of the x-axis shows the day following by the default time '00:00', e.g. '2014/1/1 00:00:00'.
How do I get rid of the time in the x labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ticklabels by `set_xticklabels()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.arange(10), index=pd.date_range( '2014/1/1', periods=10, freq='D' ) )
ax = df.plot( kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.format())
```