# Remove time from x-axis in stacked bar plot - grouby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to remove time (HH-MM-SS) from x-axis markers in all plots, generated via `groupby`.

**MWE**

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-11-30 23:50:00', freq='15min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)


df_hour = df.resample("H", how="mean")
df_day = df_hour.resample("D", how="sum")

results_group = df_day.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
results_group.plot(colormap='prism',kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

And this gives:

[image: Given output]

How can I leave only date: YYYY-MM-DD or even MM-DD ?

I've tried using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561299/2669472) but I got error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'`

```
ax = results_group.plot(colormap='prism',kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(df_day.index.format())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it. I messed up with with linked example. Here is the solution:

```
for key, group in results_group:
     ax = group.plot(colormap='prism',kind='bar', stacked=True)
     ax.set_xticklabels(df_day.index.format())
```